# Error: [hasElementById("xx")] Error response status: 17,JavaScriptError - An error occurred while executing user supplied JavaScript. Selenium error:

Tags: javascript, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, iedriverserver

I am working on Selenium with InternetExplorerDriver 32-bit to test my webapp on Windows 2016. My code is written in javascript. I am using amdc/wd as webdriver. 
The code works well on the Chrome and Safari browsers but on IE, I see the following error:

```
Error: [hasElementById("db-login",10000)] Error response status: 17, , JavaScriptError - An error occurred while executing user supplied JavaScript.
```

Selenium error:

Please suggest a fix.